# Swift how to update a subview's label and imageview using a button in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to update a subview's label text and image view photo in my storyboard when I click on a button in my TableCell. I have tried using tableView didSelectRowAt but it only works when I highlight the cell not when I use a the tableviewcell's button.

Here you can see a video of my issue.

https://www.loom.com/share/1f147a67bea548b192b654ceb78722c9

Below here you can see my code used to update the subview using didSelectRowAt

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    EditViewDescriptionLabel.text = userPostDescription[indexPath.row]
    EditPostImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: userPostImageArray[indexPath.row]))
}
```

Is there a way to update my subview by clicking on the gear icon instead?

Below is my FeedViewCell Code

```
        //
//  FeedCell.swift
//  VidaClock
//
//  Created by Irving Gonzalez on 5/30/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Viva La App. All rights reserved.
//

    import UIKit
    
    protocol EditPostDelegate {
        func gearButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
    }
    
    class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var FeedCellUserNameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var userProfilePhotoFeedCellLabel: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var dateFeedCellLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var postImageFeedCellLabel: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var likeCountFeedCellLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var postDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var documentIDLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var FeedViewGearButtonOutlet: UIButton!
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }
    
        override func layoutSubviews() {
               super.layoutSubviews()
           }
        
        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }
        
        @IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        }
        
        var delegate1: EditPostDelegate?
        
        @IBAction func postGearButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            print("postGearButtonPressed")
            delegate1?.gearButtonPressed(AnyObject.self)
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `text` for your `EditViewDescriptionLabel` label once the gear icon is pressed as well. You have a delegate to pass the message over to your viewcontroller. Within the `gearButtonPressed` call, **set the text for your label** similar to how you do in didSelectRowAt indexPath.

You need to set the `text` for your `EditViewDescriptionLabel` label once the gear icon is pressed as well. You have a delegate to pass the message over to your viewcontroller. Within the `gearButtonPressed` call, **set the text for your label** similar to how you do in didSelectRowAt indexPath.

Make your protocol like the below

(Pass data that best fits your needs. Here I am passing the description alone)

```
protocol EditPostDelegate: class {
    func gearButtonPressed(description: String)
}
```

Then on button action,

```
if let descriptionContent = postDescriptionLabel.text{
    delegate1?.gearButtonPressed(description: descriptionContent)
}
```

Then set the text for editViewDescriptionLabel in the `gearButtonPressed` method implementation and then show your view controller.
Pass the data you need to use to your view controller like so.

Also, consider naming your variables in camelCase.

Comment: What would be the best way to past it as a delegate so it will work? I do apologize for my lack of ios knowledge. I am a new programmer and am doing everything self taught.

Comment: No worries. I have edited the answer a bit to illustrate. I have shown how to pass description from your tableView cell to your main view controller. In the main VC just set the text of the label to the description that you recieve.

Comment: This fixed the issue with the Label and I will apply your method to the image view. Thank you!